# How to find by unique index in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class EmployerRestaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}

// configuration
builder.HasIndex(i => new {i.EmployerId, i.RestaurantId }).IsUnique();
```

Is it possible to perform a search on this table providing an array of unique indexes?

Something like

```
_context.EmployerRestaurant.Find({1,2},{2,2});
```

Comment: `Find` works with PK values like `Id`. What are you trying to do anyway? Why are you trying to search the bridge table instead of finding eg a Restaurant's employer, or an employer's restaurants? In EF Core 6 bridge classes like `EmployerRestaurant` may be omitted entirely

Answer (score 3):

Find is just a shorthand for DbSet.SingleOrDefault(), so you can just use it by providing a key as parameter.

The simplest way to get what you want is to filter the DbSet using a where statement:

```
_context.EmployerRestaurant.Where(e => (e.EmployerId == 1 && e.RestaurantId == 2) || e.EmployerId == 2 && e.RestaurantId == 2);
```

EF Core will translate the expression and the database will do the rest (using the index you provided).

As I suppose, if you don't know what ids to get at compile time, you can provide to `Where()` a dynamically generated expression of type `Expression<Func<EmployerRestaurant, bool>>` to get the same result:

```
List<(int empId, int RestId)>? selectedEmps = new List<(int empId, int RestId)>()
{
    (1,2),  (2,2)
};

//init an empty expression that compute to false because it's an Or operation
Expression<Func<EmployerRestaurant, bool>> predicateExpr = (e) => false;

foreach ((int empId, int RestId) in selectedEmps)
{
    //concat the real condition for each item in the array to the "dummy" expression. 
    //The resulting expression will contains all your tuples linked in a big Or expression
    Expression<Func<EmployerRestaurant, bool>> itemExpression = (e) => e.EmployerId == empId && e.RestaurantId == RestId;
    InvocationExpression tmpExpr = Expression.Invoke(itemExpression, predicateExpr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    predicateExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<EmployerRestaurant, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(predicateExpr.Body, tmpExpr), predicateExpr.Parameters);
}

//provide your generated predicate to EF Core and get the result
List<EmployerRestaurant>? emps = db.EmployerRestaurant.Where(predicateExpr).ToList();
```

To easily compose your query expression you can also use Joseph Albahari's **[PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)**.

Using the **PredicateBuilder** the foreach code will be like:

```
Expression<Func<EmployerRestaurant, bool>>? predicateExpr = PredicateBuilder.False<EmployerRestaurant>();

foreach ((int empId, int RestId) in selectedEmps)
{
    predicateExpr = predicateExpr.Or((e) => e.EmployerId == empId && e.RestaurantId == RestId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it, but tuples may help ...

```
List<(int employerId, int restaurantId)> _idsToSearchFor = new()
{
    (1, 2)
    (2, 2)
};

List<EmployerRestaurant> matches = _context.EmployerRestaurant
    .Where(er => _idsToSearchFor.Contains((er.EmployerId, er.RestaurantId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The `list.Contains(er.Id)` syntax is used to generate `ID IN (1,4,5,...)` which doesn't work with multiple columns